# Ding ding ding! Dejavu

Tags: support, status-completed, exact-duplicates

Iv'e often wondered about duplicates, most of the time they are onlyy so and so.

Check these two out:

- [How to turn curves into a series of straight lines in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/129802/how-to-turn-curves-into-a-series-of-straight-lines-in-illustrator/129807?noredirect=1#comment193207_129807)
- [Automatically transform curves to polygons in AI CC](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67302/automatically-transform-curves-to-polygons-in-ai-cc)

These top them all. It's like the exact same duplicate. It has the exact same pictures. Exact same, answer. By different persons shifted by time.

Its the exact same question as closely as possible. Amazing. Dejavu.

Comment: O_o  Nice catch! We'll be looking into this...

Comment: @joojaa you are very good [writing in Spanish too!](https://respuestas.me/q/transformar-automa-ticamente-curvas-en-poli-gonos-en-ai-cc-37599285860)

Comment: [And french](https://askfrance.me/q/transformer-automatiquement-les-courbes-en-polygones-dans-ai-cc-37599285860)

Comment: @Danielillo, lol I found that too. Image searching.

Comment: @Wolff we are multinational cosmopolitan polyglots ‍ All questions and answers are in various sites and languages

Comment: @Danielillo well I am an AI after all

Answer (score 1):

Its been taken care of, thanks for bringing it to our attention

Comment: Son-ov-a....... Merging things to make it easier and more pleasant on users and costing me 15 rep! BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA. `:) (I am kidding)